finding dual problem of the function below
I am trying to solve a question from Amir Beck's book "Introduction to nonlinear optimization"
the problem is to find the dual problem with one decision variable of the next minimization problem :
$$a^Tx + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i ln(x_i) \\ \text{s.t } x \in \Delta_n \text{which is the unit simplex}   $$
with the convention  $ 0 ln(0) = 0$
So far I have written the Lagrangian as
$$ L(x,\mu)=a^Tx + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i ln(x_i) +\mu(e^Tx-1)\\ \text{where } \mu \in R \\ x\ \geq 0 ,\text{ and } e^Tx=1 \text{ (because x is in the unit simplex)} \ $$
$ \text{ to minimize } L(x,\mu) $  and WLOG I tried to minimize it  for an arbitrary index j and I got that for the next function
$$a_jx_j +x_jln(x_j) +\mu x_j $$
the min value  is  $x_j= e^{-1-a_j-\mu}$ which is equals to $e^{-1-\mu} * e^{-a_j}$
and I don't know how to proceed from here, any suggestions, please?

You already did most of the problem. Now just wrap it up.
Your computation was done in order to compute the dual objective function $$q(\mu) = \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+} L(x, \mu).$$
You already found the $x^*$ that minimizes $L(x, \mu)$, which is $x^*_j = e^{-1 - a_j - \mu}$. Just plug it in:
\begin{align*}
q(\mu) & = L(x^*, \mu)\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i x^*_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n x^*_i \ln(x^*_i) + \mu \sum_{i = 1}^n x^*_i - \mu\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^n (a_i + \ln(x_i^*) + \mu) x^*_i\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^n (a_i + (-1 - a_i - \mu) + \mu) e^{-1 - a_i - \mu} - \mu\\
& = -\sum_{i = 1}^n e^{-1 - a_i - \mu} - \mu.
\end{align*}
The dual problem is just
$$\max_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}} -\sum_{i = 1}^n e^{-1 - a_i - \mu} - \mu.$$
